# Is using subqueries to aggregate and summarize individual users efficient?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have data in which a row is created each time customers purchase food items.  I would like to collapse the rows and summarize the data so that I can look at the relationship between the number of 2  individual food items. The following code works to give me what I need, but I am not sure whether there is a more efficient method than using a subquery?

I am using Vertica if that is helpful.

```
select
  sqq.hamburgers,
  sqq.hotdogs,
  count(1) as people
from
  (select
  sum(hamburgers) as hamburgers,
  sum(hotdogs) as hotdogs,
  person_id
from
  concessionpurchases
where
  "date" >= '2016-01-01' AND "date" <= '2016-12-31' and
  hamburgers is not null AND
  hotdogs IS NOT NULL AND
  person_id is not null
group by person_id
LIMIT 1000000) as sqq
group by hamburgers, hotdogs
order by hamburgers, hotdogs
LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this means?:

    look at the relationship between the number of 2 individual food items.

Comment: I'd like to be able to look at a crosstab of hamburgers and hotdogs.  So to know the frequency distribution of hamburger consumption for any given level of hot dog consumption and vice versa.

Comment: Ah, I see.
Yeah, I don't know that there's any way to get individual consumption numbers without grouping by person_id first. I'll try to think of some fancy analytic way to decorate rows to get equivalent results.